# Detecting two consecutive carriage returns at the end of the string

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to detect if there are 2 consecutive carriage returns in a string ontained from a textarea or multiline text box?

Here is the scenario:
In a text area, user enters ABCD "Enter" EFGHI "Enter" JKLMNOP "Enter" "Enter". After the this I need to force click event of the button - not form.submit.

Here is the default.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/Search.ascx" TagName="Search" TagPrefix="ucSearch" %>
<html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml">;
<head runat="server"> 
<title></title> </head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:scriptmanager runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>
<div>
<ucSearch:Search id="search1" runat="server" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the Search.ascx page:

```
<script language="javascript">
var inputString function doit(){inputString =  document.getElementById("search1$txtSearchText").value;
if (inputString.match(/(\n\n|\r\r|\r\n\r\n)$/)) {
    document.getElementById("search1_btnFindAssets").click();
}

</script>

<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Search.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControls_Search"%> 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchText" TextMode="MultiLine"onKeyPress="doit();" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
<br>
<asp:ButtonID="btnFindAssets"runat="server"Text="Find"onclick="btnFindAssets_Click">
```

Comment: Do you mean at the end of the string or anywhere in the string? Your title and question body do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a regular expression:

```
if (s.match(/\r\r/)) { ... }
```

The `\r` character matches carriage return. Maybe you mean line feed (`\n`)?  You might also want to handle different type of new line '\r', '\r\n', or '\n'. You can do this like this:

```
if (s.match(/\n\n|\r\r|\r\n\r\n/)) { ... }
```

If you only want the match at the end of the string, use the regex symbol `$`:

```
if (s.match(/\r\r$/)) { ... }
```

or:

```
if (s.match(/(\n\n|\r\r|\r\n\r\n)$/)) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. This works when you hit "Enter" on 3rd time.

For example, I enter "FirstSearchWord", hit "Enter" (cursor advances on nextline), "SecondSearchWord", hit "Enter" (cursor advances on nextline), hit "Enter" (this when it should post back), except I have to hit "Enter" again before page postback. Any ideas why and how to eliminate that additional "Enter"? Thanks

Comment: So you want to automatically submit after the user enters exactly two lines in the textbox?

Answer (score 3):

```
var isDoubled = yourString.indexOf("\n\n") != -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (/[\r\n]{2,}/.test(myString))
{
//TODO
}
```

Looks for two or more consecutive carrage return/new lines any where in a string.

Comment: This fails for "This contains only one\r\nnew line".

Comment: Never picks up the 2nd carriage return.